# css display:none doesn't work on android2.1 emulators webview

Tags: android, css, webview, hidden-field

My HTML hidden some element using CSS `display:none`, and I render HTML in Webview, hidden elements still show up on Android 2.1 emulators.

Test on android 2.2 / 4.0 emulators,  it works fine.

Anyone know the solution?

CSS file content:

```
.hidden{
display:none;
```

}

and add class for the hidden element

```
<input> type="text" class="hidden" id="uid" name='uid'></input>
```

Comment: How are you specifying the CSS? Can you show some code?

Comment: I mean the actual CSS instructions in the style sheet and the HTML element(s) you're applying them to. You can edit them into your question using the "edit" link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a self-closing tag, `"` instead of `'` and remove that `>` which close the tag prematurely.

```
<input type="text" class="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" />
```